# Symfony2 - GET parameters as service arguments

Tags: php, symfony, service

Currently i call a service from an action like (argument1&2 are GET parameters):

```
myAction(argument1, argument2){
    $this->get('my_service')->serviceMethod(argument1, argument2);
}
```

So my service.xml looks like :

```
<service id="..." class="...">
    <argument type="..." id="..."/>
</service>
```

Is there a way to get the GETTER arguments and launch the method in the service declaration ? :

```
<service id="..." class="...">
    <argument type="..." id="..."/>
    <argument>Request or something to get the GETTER</argument>
    <method>service's method to perform</method>
</service>
```

And so execute something like :

```
myAction(argument1, argument2){
    $this->get('my_service');
}
```

I am mostly curious about pass GETTER parameters and call a default method.
Thank you.

Comment: http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/book/service_container.html, adding a `call` option allows you to call a default method

Comment: Oh thank you i missed that, now i need to find a way to pass argument1&2 in this option.

Comment: But if you get `argument1` and `argument2` in your action, it means that the service has already been configured, not instantiated yet, so you can't pass these parameters as configuration arguments of the service

Comment: You have the point thank you. I fix it by using request stack and get the arguments in the service's method. Have a nice day :)